# Converting to an enum with no fixed underlying type out of "gamut"

Tags: c++, enums, c++14, c++17, underlyingtype

If you have an enum with no fixed underlying type, you can get its underlying type via `std::underlying_type<E>`.

```
enum no_fixed_underlying { bob = 1; };
std::underlying_type_t<no_fixed_underlying> x; // valid
```

Once you have done so, is it still considered not a *fixed* underlying type?

An enum without a fixed underlying type has a limited range, basically described as "the range of bits that could represent the values of the enum".  Conversion to the enum with a value that is "outside those bits" is undefined behavior.

So, given an enum with no fixed underlying type, it seems you cannot convert *all* values of the underlying type to the enum value.

```
enum no_fixed_underlying { bob = 1; };
std::underlying_type_t<no_fixed_underlying> x = -1; // valid
auto e = (no_fixed_underlying)x; // undefined behavior!
```

Is this correct?

In the latest draft, expr.static.cast/10 and dcl.enum/8 are what I based the above understanding on.

Comment: Looks to be.  It is interesting that expr.static.cast/10 changed from unspecified to undefined going from C++14 to C++17

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the current draft (as of Oct 2016) now prohibits that cast. The standard is getting progressively less practical and more impenetrable. It seems we're heading for a clear divergence between in-practice C++ and formal C++. Unfortunately. So, if there is such a rule, just ignore it. And if, Odin forbid, there is a compiler that won't let you do that, stop using that compiler.

Comment: See, e.g., https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56158.

Comment: @NathanOliver So you think the value was unspecified in C++14 after the `auto e=` assignment, and in the C++1z draft it is now undefined after the `auto e=` assignment?

Comment: @Yakk Yeah.  My C++14 draft has *A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to an enumeration type. The value is
unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the resulting
value is unspecified (and might not be in that range).* for [expr.static.cast]/10

Comment: @NathanOliver It's [CWG 1766](http://wg21.link/CWG1766).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: @T.C. That bug report is really scary. The, uhm, not committee secretary but whatever it's called now, suggesting that the compiler should be changed to break existing code out there, in order to conform better to a sort of sabotage-like change of the C++ standard that does not require any compiler behavior change, but opens the door for such change. Well, at least I think it's scary when the folks at the top of any international structure show such extreme lack of common sense. Where does one cancel the subscription to the world?

Comment: It appears the original motivation for the change was to make it UB so it would be verbotin (and detected) in a constant expression?  I guess other than constant expressions (where compilers are mandated to ban it), UB is little different than unspecified, in that compilers are free to specify the value.  I guess compilers are also free to format the HDD.